# How do I pass data to a component in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel-livewire

```
    class Counter extends Component
{
    public $counter = 0;
    public $name;

    public function mount($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass the name variable as parameter to the livewire component call like so `@livewire('counter', ['name' => $name])` but receiving "Undefined variable $name" error. I have been following the livewire docs too, still same error. what could possibly be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: public $name = null;

Comment: I've done that right now, but the error still persists.

Comment: public function mount($name=null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

Comment: public $name;

    public function mount($name = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

// Same error Sir. No problems, maybe my OS filesystem cannot run livewire.

Comment: Can you show the ``counter`` view file? If not, do you have ``wire:model="name"`` in the ``input`` field? ``<input type="text" name="name" wire:model="name" value="" />``

Answer (score 2):

If `$name` is not defined, then it is not a property available in the blade file where you are including Livewire. Since we don't know anything about your blade file or controllers, I can't give you a direct answer. However, you should check if `$name` is set *anywhere* and if so, if it's available in your blade view. This error is not related to Livewire. If you've simply copied the docs without checking the variables, you might as well set it right away:

`@livewire('counter', ['name' => 'Gilles'])`

Comment: Hello Sir, `$name` is defined in the component as `public $name;` with the mount() function also defined. Below is my blade file codes.

`<div>
    Name: {{ $name }}
</div>`


//This works `@livewire('counter', ['name' => 'Gilles'])`  
//This doesn't `@livewire('counter', ['name' => $name])` // This doesn't even though I have set `$name = Gilles` in the component PHP file.

What should I send here to make my issue clearer please?

Comment: The property in your Livewire component needs to get data from somewhere. That is the value that you pass. You have not defined `$name` _outside_ your Livewire component. There is no value to pass. Define `$name` _before_ instantiating your Livewire component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to component using livewire tag:

```
<livewire:show-user :post="$user">
```

Or with blade directive:

```
@livewire('show-user', ['user' => $user])
```